# VB.NET Linq to SQL - Query from table

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am starting with Linq to SQL in VB.NET, and trying to figure out how to make a simple query to a database.
I want to do it all programaticly.

I have made a connection to the database with a connectionstring, and this works fine - I can get a message if the database exists or not.
But when I want to query a table, I am missing the part where I connest to the table. I have googled a lot to find an answer for thi, but

no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code:

```
    Dim strContactString, strDBServer, strDBName, strSQLUser, strSQLPW As String

    strDBServer = "MyServer"
    strDBName = "Northwind"
    strSQLUser = "sa"
    strSQLPW = "MyPW"

    strContactString = ""
    strContactString = strContactString & "data source=" & strDBServer & ";"
    strContactString = strContactString & "initial catalog=" & strDBName & ";"
    strContactString = strContactString & "user id=" & strSQLUser & ";"
    strContactString = strContactString & "password=" & strSQLPW & ";"

    Dim MyContext As New DataContext(strContactString)

    'This works:
    If MyContext.DatabaseExists Then
        MsgBox("DB Exists")
    Else
        MsgBox("DB Does Not Exist")
    End If

    'This is the query I want to run (copied from samples I found)
    Dim TEST = From c In MyContext.Customers _
    Select c.ContactName
```

Error message:
'Customers' is not a member of 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext'.

Answer (score 2):

First off you're not supposed to use DataContext directly.

You add a new dbml file to your project and map that to the database using the editor (this means connecting visual studio to your database, then dragging the tables you want from the server explorer to the dbml editor).

That will generate for you a class colled something like NortwindDataContext (you can control this from the properties pane in the editor).

You can then use that to write your queries:

```
Dim context As New DataContext(strContactString)
Dim TEST = From c In context.Customers _
           Select c.ContactName
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right. I've never had to add anything through the UI like this to connect to any database. You CAN, but you don't have to.

Comment: If you want to use LINQ to SQL properly you *do* have to as it is based around strong typing which means it needs to read your database at design time in order to create those classes.

Comment: That's what his code looks like it's trying to achieve. It's just a push in the direction of type safety. I agree that the l2s editor is not the best tool ever devised by man but it does the job for small apps.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399375.aspx

*"Best practice is to declare a strongly typed DataContext instead of relying on the basic DataContext class and the GetTable method. A strongly typed DataContext declares all Table collections as members of the context, as in the following example."*

As long as the db is connected correctly, this may be your problem.